# Ubuntu 12.04 does not recognize Kingston DT108 16GB USB drive

Tags: 12.04, usb-drive, ram

I bought a Kingston DT108 16GB USB pen drive and Ubuntu did not recognize it. What should i do?

Output of `dmesg | tail` after connecting pen drive:

```
[ 1455.253010] CPU5: Package power limit notification (total events = 488)   
[ 1455.253013] CPU1: Package power limit notification (total events = 489)  
[ 1455.263966] CPU4: Package power limit normal  
[ 1455.263969] CPU2: Package power limit normal  
[ 1455.263972] CPU0: Package power limit normal  
[ 1455.263975] CPU6: Package power limit normal  
[ 1455.263998] CPU1: Package power limit normal  
[ 1455.264001] CPU5: Package power limit normal  
[ 1455.264004] CPU7: Package power limit normal  
[ 1455.264007] CPU3: Package power limit normal
```

Comment: What is the output of "dmesg | tail" after connecting your pen drive?

Comment: [ 1455.253010] CPU5: Package power limit notification (total events = 488)
[ 1455.253013] CPU1: Package power limit notification (total events = 489)
[ 1455.263966] CPU4: Package power limit normal
[ 1455.263969] CPU2: Package power limit normal
[ 1455.263972] CPU0: Package power limit normal
[ 1455.263975] CPU6: Package power limit normal
[ 1455.263998] CPU1: Package power limit normal
[ 1455.264001] CPU5: Package power limit normal
[ 1455.264004] CPU7: Package power limit normal
[ 1455.264007] CPU3: Package power limit normal

Comment: Weird. I was hoping that there would be some trace of kernel log that said it had at least seen a device plugged in... I'm sorry I can't help you much here.

Answer (score 0):

first format the USB in NTFS. just use fidisk-l to check wether if it is showing in the device list WITH NTFS file system. Remember the device name and mount the device using command `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt  //assuming sda2 is NTFS formatted USB device.`

edit: I recommend you to format the USB device as ntfs for it makes easy on a linux system to check the ntfs device and figure out what it is.

Comment: I do not understand

Comment: idea behind it is simple. I just want to check if the usb is plugged in. If it does, then mounting it may solve the problem. Other wise you can check further for answer. Whats the output of `sudo fdisk -l` ?

Comment: I do not recognize it:

Comment: Disco /dev/sda: 500.1 GB
Unidades = sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico / físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Identificador del disco: 0x00013fd6

Dispositivo Inicio    Comienzo      Fin      Bloques  Id  Sistema
/dev/sda1   *        2048    97656831    48827392   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       968959998   976771071     3905537    5  Extendida
/dev/sda3        97656832   968957951   435650560   83  Linux
/dev/sda5       968960000   976771071     3905536   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Comment: have you formatted it with ntfs file system and still not getting any ntfs devices listed? I mean which file system your USB device is having?

Comment: How do you format? If I do not figure anywhere.

Comment: check out if anything is listed here: `sudo lsusb` . dont you know how to format the device with a particulat file system?

Comment: Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:a014 Alcor Micro Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Wireless Mouse M305

Comment: That does not appear!

Comment: then its seems that ports are not proper. does other pendrive on that port are detected?

Comment: Other usb if I detect it.

Comment: Hell, what do I do?

Comment: i mean, if that is a usb port problem , then it would also not detect other usb you would plug in the same port you are plugging in the current usb. does any other working usb gives you similar problem if you insert at that port?

Comment: Usually, I got it, thanks to a MAC. I formated in NTFS using a MAC. Thank you very much everyone for your help really.
A greeting very strong, close the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does that particular USB port work when other devices are plugged in?  It is possible that that USB hub on your machine isn't working under Ubuntu.   It should always recognize that there is a device being plugged in -- do `dmesg |grep /dev` and see what the last device comes out to be.

As a test, plug a mouse into that USB port and see if it is working as expected (`watch "dmesg | tail"`,  CTRL+C to break out)

Another possibility is that, the device requires more power than the port can provide, but whatever the case, try another USB port on your machine and see if the behavior continues.

Comment: I am Spanish and I can not understand what you say. Leave it, thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Usually, I got it, thanks to a MAC. I formated in NTFS using a MAC. Thank you very much everyone for your help really.
A greeting very strong, close the issue.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I understand- are you talking about Mac OSX?  You cannot format a device to NTFS format using a Mac that I was aware of.

Comment: Well if you have the option of NTFS what happens next with a new name: Windows NT compression or something.

Comment: You can use Disk Utility to format USB flash drives.